# Access Delphi record fields via . or ^

Tags: delphi

I came across something in the Delphi language that I hadn't noticed before. Consider a simple record and a pointer to that record:

```
TRecord = record
     value : double;
end;
PTRecord = ^TRecord;
```

Now declare a variable of type PTRecord:

```
var x : PTRecord;
```

and create some space:

```
x := new (PTRecord);
```

I noticed that I can access the value field using both the '.' notation and the '^.' notation. Thus the following two lines appear to be operationally equivalent, the compiler doesn't complain and runtime works fine:

```
x.value := 4.5;
x^.value := 2.3;
```

I would have thought that '^.' is the correct and only way to access value? My question is, is it ok to use the simpler dot notation or will I run into trouble if I don't use the pointer indirection '^.'? Perhaps this is well known behavior but it's the first time I've come across it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is perfectly sound and safe to omit the caret. Of course, logic demands the caret, but since the expression `x.value` doesn't have a meaningful intepretation in its own, the compiler will assume you actually mean `x^.value`. This feature is a part of the so-called 'extended syntax'. You can read about this [at the documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE4/en/Pointers_and_Pointer_Types_%28Delphi%29#Using_Extended_Syntax_with_Pointers).

Comment: Interesting, I was unaware of the extended syntax. Thanks for the link.

Comment: It was introduced for objects, then expanded to records as well

Answer (score 4):

When [Extended syntax](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE4/en/Extended_syntax_%28Delphi%29) is in effect (the default), you can omit the caret when referencing pointers.

Answer (score 4):

Delphi has supported that syntax for close to two decades. When you use the `.` operator, the compiler will apply the `^` operator implicitly. Both styles are correct. There is no chance for your program doing the wrong thing since there is no case where presence or absence of the `^` will affect the interpretation of the subsequent `.` operator.

Although this behavior is controlled by the "extended syntax" option, nobody *ever* disables that option. You can safely rely on it being set in all contexts. It also controls availability of the implicit `Result` variable, and the way character pointers are compatible with array syntax.

Answer (score 1):

This is called *implicit pointer dereferencing for the structured types* and inherited from the Delphi 1. This language extension aims to make accessing members of classes (classes are [structured types](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE4/en/Structured_Types) and also instances are implicit pointers) by the means of membership operator (`.`) only, avoiding requirement for explicit dereference operator (`^`).

You can safely rely on the presence of this extension in the all Delphi compilers. For more flexibility you can test for the presence of this extension by using `$IFOPT X+` conditional directive.

Comment: That explanation sounds appealing, but . operator still works  for classes in X- mode